# When to use Props and when State in Preact sub components

Tags: reactjs, preact

I'm learning preact, but this might concern React as well.

Say I have a list of checkboxes, each with some additional HTML, like this (Typescript):

```js
export class MyCheckbox extends Component<Props, State> {

    render(props, state) {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={state.checked}
                    onChange={props.onUpdate}
                    />
                <div>
                    {props.name}
                    <!-- other GUI elements -->
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then, these components are used in a higher-level component like this:

```js
render(props, state) {

    return (
        <div class={style.finding}>
            <form>
                { this.elements
                    .map(el => (
                        <MyCheckbox name={el.name} checked={el.checked} onUpdate={this.onUpdate()} />
                    ))
                }
            </form>
        </div>        
    </div>
);
```

As you can see, the higher-level component tells the checkbox whether it should be checked or not. So the `Props` object of the checkbox has a property `checked` on it, which determines whether the checkbox should be checked when it becomes visible.

However, we also need a `checked` property on the `State`, because the user might click the checkbox and thus update it. So `Props.checked` means "initially checked" and `State.checked` means "currently checked".

But if the user clicks the checkbox, the `onUpdate` method will update the `this.elements` model on the higher-level component. This will trigger `render()` on the higher-level component, which in turn passes the new `Props.checked` to the checkbox.

This means, the `Props` of the checkbox will act like a state. It becomes updated when the user clicks the checkbox, and then the new state is passed to the checkbox.

Is that normal? Or is my design somehow off? Does the child component need a state at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the way to go is to apply the **Stateful parent and stateless child** pattern.

In your case *MyCheckbox* should be stateless (should not contain a `checked` state variable) and the checked value should be a property.

The state of the checked value should be handled by the parent state.

```
export class MyCheckbox extends Component<Props, State> {
    render(props, state) {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={props.checked}
                    onChange={props.onUpdate} />
                <div>
                    {props.name}
                    <!-- other GUI elements -->
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

parent:

```
export class Parent extends Component<Props, State> {
    ...
    render(props, state) {
        return (
            <div class={style.finding}>
                <form>
                    { this.elements
                        .map(el => (
                            <MyCheckbox name={el.name} checked={this.isChecked(el)} onUpdate={this.onUpdate()} />
                        ))
                    }
                </form>
            </div>        
        </div>
    );

    isChecked(elem) {
        // use this.state to verify to return a boolean representing the checkbox checked state
    }
}
```

Making a component stateless is always good. Having a prop and a state value that represents the same aspect of a component is a bit ugly.

Hope this helps